# MEAN stack issue

Tags: node.js, angular

i'm relatively new to the stack MEAN and still learning it.

I got an error which i don't see where is the error.this is from the from in Angular.
Here is the ouput of my error:

> Type '() => any' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.Property 'push' is missing in type '() => any'.

```
    import { ApplicationService } from './../../services/applicationService/application.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: "cc-search",
  templateUrl: "./search.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./search.component.css"]
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {
  applications = [];
  constructor(private applicationService: ApplicationService) {}

  ngOnInit() {}
  searchApplications(searchData) {
    this.applicationService
      .searchApplication(searchData)
      .subscribe(
        data => this.applications = data,
        error => console.error(error)
      );
  }
}
```

and from server side:
i don't know what kind of error is it, probably my route is not right as i can't get the info.

```
const getAllApplications = () => {
    return [...addedApplications, ...initialApplications];
};

api.get('search/:term/:place?', (req, res) => {
    const term = req.params.term.toLowerCase().trim();
    let place = req.params.place;
    let applications = getAllApplications().filter(j => (j.description.toLowerCase().includes(term) || j.title.toLowerCase().includes(term)));
    console.log('test');
    if (place) {
        place = place.toLowerCase().trim();
        applications = applications.filter(j => (j.city.toLowerCase().includes(place)));
    }
    res.json({ success: true, applications: applications });
});
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you see this error? What line no. does it reference?

Comment: for angular it's on the line : data => this.applications = data,

Comment: add the definiton of the searchApplication method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't declaring a type for the result of your subscribe. You should explicitly specify the type of the result:

```
this.applicationService
    .searchApplication(searchData)
    .subscribe(
        (data: Application[]) => this.applications = data,
        error => console.error(error)
        );
```

I assume that your model is `Application`

Comment: i declare applications as [].

Comment: I any case you should declare the type of the data in subscribe. In my opinion it should be of type of some model @AznYouth